# Problem when installing nodejs with nvm windows

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, nvm-windows

Installing nodejs with nvm windows did not create directory AppData/Roaming/npm. Is that the right behaviour? Because I got some error when I did npm run build.

Comment: What is the output of `npm -v`?

Comment: What is some error when you `npm run Build`?

Comment: @ShamsNahid Nahid my version of npm 2.15.11

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi Error webpack is not recognize as an internal or external command.

Comment: Your nvm installation is working properly, Although you are using older version of `node` as well as `npm`. Try to switch a newer version of `node.js`

Answer (score 0):

npm created for every nodeJS version you install at:
`/AppData/Roaming/**nvm**/[node_version_number]/`